# Altair plot, show vertical bars

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
dicta = {
    'date':['2019-06-29', '2019-06-30', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-02', '2019-07-03'],
    'amount':[-9.35, -6.42, -13.55, -12.88, -12.24] }
dataset = pd.DataFrame(dicta)
alt.Chart(dataset).mark_bar().encode(
    x = "date:T",
    y = "amount:N"    
)
```

I'm not sure why this generates horizontal bars, instead of vertical bars by default.
How can I change it? I would like to see a bar per day, up to the amount for the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I encoded the numerical column with N. But this is for nominal data, and got Altair confused. Need to use Q/ Quantitative